# Help to simplify the construction of the set of solutions of a system of two equations

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, systems-of-equations

I would like your help to simplify the construction of the set of solutions of a system of two equations. Answering the question requires knowing the definition of cumulative distribution function (hereafter CDF).

In short a CDF is a function $F$

1) from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,1]$

2) weakly increasing

3) $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}F(x)=1$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}F(x)=0$

[see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) for a more formal definition of CDF]

---

**The system of equations**

Consider the following system of equations
$$
(\star)\hspace{1cm}
\begin{cases}
a=F(x)\\
b=F(y)
\end{cases}
$$
where

- $a,b$ are **known** parameters both in $[0,1]$
- $F,x,y$ are **the unknowns** with $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $y\in \mathbb{R}$, $F\in \mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}\equiv \{F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1] \text{ s.t. } F \text{ is a continuous CDF}\}$

---

**Fact 1 (not used)**

For any $F\in \mathcal{F}$ there exists $(x,y)$ satisfying $(\star)$. Specifically, $x=Q_F(a), y=Q_F(b)$ solve the system where $Q_F$ is the quantile function associated with $F$.

[the quantile function is basically the inverse of the CDF, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) for a definition]

---

**Fact 2**

If $(F,x,y)$ solves $(\star)$ then $(F^{\mu},x+\mu,y+\mu)$ solves $(\star)$ too, where $F^{\mu}$ is obtained by "**relocating**" $F$ according to $\mu$, $\forall \mu \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

**Fact 3**

If $(F,x,y)$ solves $(\star)$ then $(F_{\sigma},\sigma x,\sigma y)$ solves $(\star)$ too, where $F_{\sigma}$ is obtained by "**rescaling**" $F$ according to $\sigma$, $\forall \sigma>0$.

---

**Clarification on "relocating" and "rescaling"**

I'm very naive in the way I think about relocating and rescaling.

Suppose that $F$ is the standard normal CDF. Then, relocating $F$ according to $\mu$ is intended as considering the CDF of the normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $1$ (if you look at the graphs [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) you see that the plot of the CDF is horizontally shifted by $\mu$). Rescaling $F$ according to $\sigma$ is intended as considering the CDF of the normal with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ (if you look at the graphs [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) you see that the plot of the CDF is rescaled by $\sigma$).

I guess that something similar can be always done for any (not necessarily normal) CDF $F\in \mathcal{F}$. Please advise me on this if I'm wrong.

---

**What I want to do**

Imagine that I have an algorithm searching for the set of solutions of $(\star)$.

When I run such an algorithm, for each group of solutions equivalent up to a "**relocation**" and up to a "**rescaling**", I want to save only one solution from the group.

---

**My idea to achieve what I want to do**

Instead of solving $(\star)$, solve wrto $(F,x,y)\in \mathcal{F}\times \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$
$$
(\star \star)\hspace{1cm}
\begin{cases}
a=F(x)\\
b=F(y)
\end{cases} \text{ s.t. $x=0$ and $y\in \{-1,1\}$}
$$
Attempted proof:

- Notice that, by Fact 2, if $(F,x,y)$ solves $(\star)$ then $(F^{-x},0,y-x)$ solves $(\star)$ too.
- Notice that, by Fact 3, if $(F,x,y)$ solves $(\star)$ then $(F_{|y|},\frac{x}{|y|}, \frac{y}{|y|})$ solves $(\star)$ too.

Hence, by solving $(\star \star)$, we achieve my objective.

**Question**: is my idea correct? Is it "without loss of generality"?

---

**Further terminology**

For readers familiar with econometrics, the procedure above is related to "scale and location normalisations in discrete choice models".

Comment: One counter example: in the original problem with $F$ limited to the family of normal distributions and the case $a=0$, there are solutions (ie. values for $\mu$, $\sigma$, $y$) for a given $b>0$. There is no solution, however, for your modified statement of the problem.

Comment: Your counter-example is tricky because, for the family of distributions you are considering, $F(x)=0 \leftrightarrow x=-\infty$ which is a limiting case. I understand I need to address this issue too. However, for the moment, could you find a counterexample not involving $x=\infty$ or $x=-\infty$?

Comment: For example, if $a=0, b=0.3$ and $F$ is the family of uniform distributions, then $(\star \star)$ has a solution. For example $F$ uniform in $[4/7, 2]$ satisfies $(\star \star)$.